# Dataflow GroupBy -> multiple outputs based on keys

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Is there any simple way that I can redirect the output of GroupBy into multiple output files based on Group keys?

```
Bin.apply(GroupByKey.<String, KV<Long,Iterable<TableRow>>>create())
.apply(ParDo.named("Print Bins").of( ... ) 
.apply(TextIO.Write.to(*Output file based on key*))
```

If Sink is the solution, would you please share a sample code w/ me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beam 2.2 will include an API to do just that - `TextIO.write().to(DynamicDestinations)`, see [source](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L162). For now, if you'd like to use this API, you can use the 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT version. Note that this API is experimental and might change in Beam 2.3 or onwards.